# Harmonic function and Poincaré metric

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $u$ be a harmonic function on the unit disk $\Delta$, taking values in $[0,1]$.

1. Is it true that this implies that $u$ is Lipschitz for the Poincaré metric ?
2. If not, what can be said about a harmonic function satisfying this property ?

I am thinking the answer to 1. might be true, but I'm not sure. I was thinking that since the unit disk is simply connected, we can find globally a holomorphic function of which $u$ is the real part and maybe somehow manage to apply Schwarz Pick lemma. But I'm not convinced it always possible to do this, and I would be interested in a characterization (ideally) or necessary conditions on $u$ to verify this.

Comment: Harmonic with respect to what Laplacian? The Euclidean Laplacian or the the Laplacian coming from the Poincaré metric?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'd say euclidean. when you define the laplacian as $dd^c$ or $\partial \overline{\partial}$ (up to constants I never remember), you don't need a metric, do you ?

Comment: Actually yes, because the codifferential depends on the metric.

Comment: I may be wrong but is seems to me that $\partial$ and $\overline{\partial}$ as exterior derivatives on forms didn't depend on the metric ? if not, I mean euclidean laplacian

Comment: You are right. I have only read $dd^c.$

Comment: Both possibilities to consider harmonicity are equivalent: $(1.6)$ in  https://www.math.tugraz.at/discrete/publications/projects/files/woess-disk-tree.pdf

Comment: hang on, lipschitz for the hyperbolic metric looks suspiciously close to Harnack's equality... (also thanks for the link,i'll clarify the relationship with metrics in my head)

Comment: If it takes values in $(-1,1)$ then it is Lipschitz: page $2$ http://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.4006.pdf and original result http://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.4905v3.pdf.

Comment: thanks a lot ! (wow I did not expect this to be such a recent result). if you make an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Well, actually it is not my answer. I only hope it would be useful to you. When I see the question  I thought that the answer could be standard, more or less, in same way. But it seem unsolved, to my knowledge.

Comment: Thank you very much, anyway. I forgot sometimes to be polite.

Answer (score 1):

As mfl pointed out, this is true. In fact, the result is not specific to complex analysis: it holds in higher dimensions too. This is how it is presented in the book [Harmonic Function Theory](http://www.axler.net/HFT.html) (free download) by Axler,  Bourdon, and  Ramey:

> Theorem 6.26: Suppose $u$ is a real-valued harmonic function on $B_n$ (unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$) and $|u|<1$ on $B_n$. Then 
>   $$|\nabla u(0)|\le \frac{2V(B_{n-1})}{V(B_n)} \tag1$$

The constant on the right in (1) is not so important: we only need to know that it depends only on $n$. If we have harmonic $u:B_n(r)\to (-1,1)$, where $r$ is the radius of the ball, then applying the above to $v(x)=u(rx)$ yields
$$r |\nabla u(0)|\le \frac{2V(B_{n-1})}{ V(B_n)} \tag2$$

Returning to the unit ball and an arbitrary point $x\in B_n$, apply (2) in the ball of radius $1-|x|$ centered at $x$. The result is 
$$(1-|x|) |\nabla u(x)|\le \frac{2V(B_{n-1})}{ V(B_n)} \tag3$$
The quantity on the left is almost the gradient of $u$ in the Poincaré metric; just multiply by $(1+|x|)$, which is at most $2$.

Comment: More generally, it holds for Riemannian manifolds of bounded geometry due to Yau's gradient inequality.